# Search in elasticsearch without tokenizing keywords

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": [
               {
                   "simple_query_string": {
                       "query": "template testing",
                       "fields": [
                           "tag^8.0",
                           "title^10.0",
                           "body^3.0"
                       ],
                       "flags": -1,
                       "default_operator": "or",
                       "analyze_wildcard": false,
                       "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false,
                       "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                       "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                       "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                       "boost": 1
                   }
               },

           ],
           "filter": [
               {
                   "terms": {
                       "assetCourse.assetType": [
                           "epub"
                       ],
                       "boost": 1
                   }
               }
           ],

           "adjust_pure_negative": true,
           "boost": 1
       }
   },

 "sort": { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}

}
```

**I want to search for the exact keyword 'template testing' first then tokenized search with 'template' and 'testing' but with my query it only search for 'template' and 'testing' seperately. please help me improve the query.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a simple **match** query which will order the results with both terms occurring at the top followed by results with individual terms.
You can add other params using this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [

        {
          "match": {
            "tag": {
              "query": "template testing"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "template testing"
            }
          }
        },

        {
          "match": {
            "body": {
              "query": "template testing"
            }
         }

        }
        ]
  }
}
}
```

Comment: it returns nothing, and i only want to search in few fields.

Comment: thanks @arnav it's working, just close the should parameter after last match body and you missed one closing curly brace. I have edited it.